# How to have a blockingcollection with multiple consumers

Tags: c#, blockingcollection

I'm trying to achieve having one producer and multiple consumers using BlockingCollection. Created such a code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestConcQueue
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Producer producer = new Producer();

            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(TaskAction, new object[] {i, producer}));
            }

            while (true)
            {
                string line = Console.ReadLine();
                if (line == "q")
                {
                    producer.Add("x");
                    break;
                }

                producer.Add(line);
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }

        private static void TaskAction(object o)
        {
            object[] data = (object[])o;
            int id = (int)data[0];
            Producer producer = (Producer)data[1];

            Console.WriteLine("Task with ID " + id + " started");
            foreach (string value in producer.Consumer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task with ID " + id + " consumed value " + value);
                if (value == "x")
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Task with ID " + id + " finished");            
        }
    }


    public class Producer
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _items = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
        private readonly BlockingCollection<string> _producer;

        public Producer()
        {
            _producer = new BlockingCollection<string>(_items);
        }

        public void Add(string item)
        {
            _producer.Add(item);
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> Consumer
        {
            get { return _producer.GetConsumingEnumerable(); }
        }
    }
}
```

but any time I add an element only 1 Task will consume that value, all other are missing it. How do I simulate multiple consumers.

I cannot use Rx or TPL libraries.

Thx

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are attempting to do but realize that the method GetConsumingEnumerable() will dequeue the item from the concurrentqueue in the blocking collection.  The first task that calls Consume will get value and all subsequent ones will get nothing because the item has been removed from the queue.  If you need to send the value to multiple methods/tasks then have a controller method that calls the Consume method and starts up the various tasks.

Comment: Multiple consumers means that multiple threads are processing items, not that all consumers get each item. Are you looking for something that will send a single message to multiple listeners?